# How to prevent PowerShell script from immediate close when the timer event is run?

Tags: powershell, intervals

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script for my own use to run it at Windows start up, so it volume up gradually. It works well when I copy the script and paste it in the PowerShell window and click enter, but it does not work when I save the script content in the .ps1 file and *Run it with PowerShell* from the context menu. It is immediately closed and doesn't wait until the condition from interval is done.

```
$timer = New-Object Timers.Timer

$iter = 0;

$action = {
  $iter += 1;
  Write-Host "Interval: $iter";
  if ($iter -eq 10) {
    Unregister-Event thetimer;
    pause;
  }
} 
$timer.Interval = 1000  #3 seconds

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName elapsed –SourceIdentifier thetimer -Action $action

$timer.Start()
```

I simplified the script. What command and where should I use, to hang the script till the interval event is finished?

Answer (score 1):

The `pause` command inside the timer scriptblock doesn't affect the parent process from which you're starting the timer.

To keep the parent window open until the timer finishes you could add a loop checking the job status:

```
...
$timer.Start()

do {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    $job = Get-Job -Name 'thetimer'
} while ($job.State -in 'NotStarted', 'Running')
```

Comment: To keep the parent window open, I would just use [`Wait-Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/wait-event?view=powershell-6).